# Is there a react-native library with Azure AD broker authentication for MDM devices

Tags: react-native, azure-active-directory, mdm, azure-authentication, intune

I am building a cross platform application with React Native for MDM managed devices. The authentication to the Azure AD should be SSO (automatically based on the work profile / intune information) and not through a classic WebView.

I heard that this could be done by Broker Authentication Support (e.g. for Microsoft Authenticator) but I couldn't find any library supporting that. I've tried following libraries but most of them are not maintained anymore or they are following the WebView approach: `react-native-ms-adal`, `react-native-azure-adal`, `react-native-azure-ad`.

Has anyone build such an use case or does know a working library?

Comment: refer this https://vmurin.github.io/react-native-azure-auth/ or this   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/developer/app-sdk-android

Comment: the problem is that the authentication has to be brokered, not through a classic interactive webview authentication. having a managed device environment the authentication through e.g. microsoft authenticator delivers a device id which has to be requested in order to get the access token.

Comment: Hi @Mike, if the provided answer resolved your issue, you may mark it as answer or upvote it so that others who encounter the similar issue, it may be useful for them or community members.

Comment: Hey @KartikBhiwapurkar-MT I want to test it out coming week and I will then come up with an answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

•   To enable broker authentication support for react native applications on Azure AD MDM managed devices, you will have to ensure that the following **method is enabled for broker component support in ADAL for Android 3.0.0**: -

```
 Microsoft.ADAL.AuthenticationSettings.setUseBroker(true);
```

**Developer needs to register special ‘redirectUri’ for broker usage**. ‘RedirectUri’ is in the format of ***‘msauth://packagename/Base64UrlencodedSignature’***. Thus, since `ADALis deprecated and MSAL is in place for it, you will have to use MSAL for Android 3.0+ library`. For that purpose, you will have to install dependencies and declare it on MSAL as below: -

```
 dependencies {
  implementation 'com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:3.0.+'
  }
```

Thus, in this way, you can configure Azure AD broker authentication in MDM devices. For more information, kindly refer to the below documentation link: -

**https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android**

**https://github.com/northwesternmutual/azure-activedirectory-library-for-react-native/blob/master/README.md#android-quirks**

Comment: I have implemented the React Native Wrapper documented by northwesternmutual but I still have a problem regarding Broker Authentication. I have set the corresponding method to ensure Broker Authentication inside my React Native component but I still receive an interactive Microsoft Authentication WebView.